# How to give access of s3 bucket residing in Account A to different iam users from multiple aws accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, policy, bucket

I am working on aws SAM project and i have a requirement of giving access to my S3 bucket to multiple iam users from unknown aws accounts but i can't make bucket publicly accessible. I want to secure my bucket as well as i want any iam user from any aws account to access the contents of my S3 bucket. Is this possible?

Below is the policy i tried and worked perfectly.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1616828964582",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1616828940658",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/STS_Role_demo"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::new-demo-bkt/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Above policy is for one user but i want any user from other AWS account to access my contents without making the bucket and objects public so how can i achieve this?

Comment: You can't do this. If you don't know the other accounts, you have to make bucket public.

Answer (score 0):

This might be possible using a set of Conditions on the incoming requests.

I can think of two options:

1. You create an IAM role that your SAM application uses even when running in other accounts
2. You create S3 bucket policies that allow unknown users access

If you decide to look into S3 bucket policies, I suggest using an [S3 Access Point](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-points.html) to better manage access policies.

> Access points are named network endpoints that are attached to buckets
> that you can use to perform S3 object operations, such as GetObject
> and PutObject. Each access point has distinct permissions and network
> controls that S3 applies for any request that is made through that
> access point. Each access point enforces a customized access point
> policy that works in conjunction with the bucket policy that is
> attached to the underlying bucket.

You can use a combination of [S3 Conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html#amazons3-policy-keys) to restrict access. For example, your SAM application could include specific condition keys when making S3 requests, and the bucket policy then allows access based on those conditions.

You can also apply [global IAM conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#AvailableKeys) to S3 policies.

This isn't great security though, malicious actors might be able to figure out the headers and spoof requests to your bucket. As noted on some conditions such as `aws:UserAgent`:

> This key should be used carefully. Since the `aws:UserAgent` value is
> provided by the caller in an HTTP header, unauthorized parties can use
> modified or custom browsers to provide any `aws:UserAgent` value that
> they choose. As a result, `aws:UserAgent` should not be used to
> prevent unauthorized parties from making direct AWS requests. You can
> use it to allow only specific client applications, and only after
> testing your policy.